# How do redirect STDOUT out of XCode compiled Command Line executable?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, bash, command

I have a C++ program that writes to stdout that I am trying to compile into a command line utility in XCode. I need the program compiled into a release build (which it seems, XCode calls an Archive - go figure), not run it as debug.

I basically want to pipe the output of my program into a textfile like this

> MyProgram > TextFile.txt

I can compile the program into a command line and run it like this via a Bash shell like this:

> Open MyProgram

This spawns a new process (not what I want). However, I could live with that if this worked:

> Open MyProgram > TextFile.txt

...But it doesnt :-(. If I try to just run MyProgram directly from Bash, I get the error: **-bash: MyProgram: command not found.**

What am I doing wrong? How can I compile my command line tool to NOT require the Open command under Mac OSX?

Thanks for any help you can provide. I am picking up C++ on the Mac platform and I am beginning to find it quite it a bit more troublesome than Visual Studio. Does it ever get less painful to work with? :-)

Comment: Wait, you're running "Open MyProgram" in Bash? Don't you mean just "MyProgram", or possibly "./MyProgram"?

Comment: Hi notfed. Yes. I am indeed running it like that. What i WANT to do is to just run MyProgram as you describe. But when I do, I get the "command not found" error.

Comment: If your program is named "MyProgram", and is in the current directory, you type "./MyProgram" to run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make your project a `Command Line Tool`. This will make it so you can run it from the command line directly.
- Run it by typing `./MyProgram` or `./MyProgram > TextFile.txt` not `open MyProgram`.

Comment: My program is already a Command Line Tool project, it does not seem to be enough? Is there some config setting I have to set in the project?

Comment: No, it should output a binary file which you can run by typing `/path/to/MyProgram` or `./MyProgram` if you are already in the same directory as your program.

Comment: I missed the requirement for the current path Greg. It seems that Open will search in current path, but typing the executable from bash will not.